# MySQL : What's The Easiest Way To Convert char(15) 5-Nov-17 Into a Date Format?

Tags: mysql

I have a column named Install_date of type char(15) with dates written in this format: "5-Nov-17"

What's the easiest way to convert that column to a date type so that I can sort it please?

Comment: `str_to_date(install_date, '%e-%b-%y')`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya long time no see!

Comment: @Nick yeah.. busy with some new product development.. posted a question couple of days back: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59499000/2469308

Answer (score 0):

```
select STR_TO_DATE("5-Nov-17","%d-%M-%y")
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cabdc038d3653e072fcb37454b769983